# Emacs client - Keep frame until all buffers are closed

Tags: emacs, frame, emacsclient

I'm using Emacs with the server in daemon mode.

When I go to the buffers menu, I can see all the buffers that the server has open. Is there a way to keep the Emacs client frame open until all the modified buffers have been saved?

If I close a buffer via `C-x k`, one of two things happen:

1. The frame switches to the next buffer in the stack.
2. The frame dies, if I happen to close the buffer that I opened Emacs client with.

Is there a way to always enforce the first behavior regardless of which buffer I kill?

All my searching has lead to answers to other questions.

Comment: Why kill the buffer? Have you tried editing the buffer list (C-x C-b) instead?

Comment: Because i've finished with it and having files open confuses the build tools that I'm using. The buffer list that you refer to offers no value when it comes to closing files.